# how to save data when Fragment is replaced

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

first of all i've tried all the solution available but i still doesnt get the answer of this question.

i have an Activity that has few fragments that will populate a ViewPager, the way i populate the viewPager is this way.

```
fragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragment.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.homepageVp, newFrag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

suppouse there is Fragment A and i replace it With Fragment B using above code, and then here is my question, is it possible to move from Fragment A to Fragment B and move back to Fragment A using above code but still containing data from previous Replace (first one).

i've tried using

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(VAR_KEY, jsonResult);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    jsonResult = savedInstanceState.getString(VAR_KEY);
}
```

inside Fragment A, this is my understanding that onSaveInstanceState is executed to save jsonResult variable so later when my activity is created again the onActivityCreated is executed and put the previous value into jsonResult variable. but that didnt work, so perhaps there is a mistake(s) that i made, or its my understanding of Fragment LifeCycle that isn't correct.

Comment: why not you create a singleton class to store the json and access it from anywhere?

Comment: have you tried onCreateView instead of onActivityCreated?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to recreate fragment in `viewPager` just set `offscreenPageLimit` in your `viewPager` like this:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(/*Total no of fragments*/);
```